# How can I build other people's projects from github?

Tags: java

I suspect this is not as hard as I'm making it but I'm having trouble understanding how to build other people's source into jar files I can use for my own projects.

For example(please make the answer general so I can apply it to other sources), I'm looking at https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis and the source seems newer than the provided jars(for which I noticed a few bugs), so I wanted to try to build it so its like the provided jars(this way I can test it in my project).  I know how to clone the repository but I don't feel like copying/pasting or import one file at a time into eclipse to export a jar.

Is there something easy that I can go into a folder and run a command to get the jar(my understanding jar's are just zipped files)?

Comment: You are checking out source code. You need to build the project. It would appear they use maven, so `mvn clean install` ought to do the trick.

Comment: I think the pom there is just for publishing to a repo. I think it is using gradle.

Comment: Is maven applicable to all java source? or javac? I want to read and build alot of difference packages to learn, and is there one tool I can use for this or is it dependent on what the developer used?

Comment: @Synesso - I'd have to pull it and try, it has the compiler plugin and the dependencies set up in the pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each project will provide its own way of building and packaging. There are some standard methods. The project you linked to is using a tool called [Gradle](http://gradle.org/).

Try running `gradlew` to see if that will build the project for you. If that fails, you could learn to use Gradle. Alternatively you could contact the project owner and ask for a new release.

Comment: Is there a standard way? If I learn gradle will it work on all java source?

Comment: @learningJava - there are several "standard ways"; people use the build tools they prefer, and there's a few of them. You need to learn how to use these tools if you're going to pull down source and compile it.

Comment: @BrianRoach okay good to know, but I'm trying to figure out..say I like Gradle..will it work on all java projects or do I have to use what the developer used when making his software?

Comment: No, Gradle is just one of many build tools. You can also build and package without using a tool (just `javac` and `jar`). But for this project it will be easiest with Gradle, I believe. Try the `gradlew` command and if it fails contact the project owner. That's what I would try.

Comment: @Synesso Thank you so much.  I am downloading gradle and will play around with it.. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the project using `git clone` then build it using `make`, `maven`, `ant` or whatever is given there.

In your case doing a `git clone https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis.git` will clone the repo then you use [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) to build the project. Since I didn't use it, see [their tutorial](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#tutorial_using_tasks) for more